# Sitecore not respecting II7 URL Rewrite module

Tags: iis, iis-7, url-rewriting, sitecore, sitecore6

I am trying to get the IIS7 URL Rewrite module working with Sitecore. I imported some rules and successfully tested them, but when I attempt to go to a URL I've setup a redirect for I get the Sitecore 404 page instead. So it's as if Sitecore is intercepting the page request before the URL Rewrite module has a chance to.

Sample rule:

```
<rule name="Imported Rule 1">
                <match url="/pastsub(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.domain.net" redirectType="Found" />
</rule>
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Adding **stopProcessing="true"** to the rule will probably solve your problem:

```
<rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="/pastsub(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.domain.net" redirectType="Found" />
</rule>
```